# How to remove Split APK

Tags: android, react-native, xamarin, adb, android-source

I am trying to uninstall the split APK. I am working on the app where I need to merge and remove split APK's. Split APK installation is working but I am not getting any way to remove the installed split APK's. As per my requirement, The split APK uninstallation should work on non-rooted devices.

I got this function on android documentation but don't know to how to use it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.Session#removeSplit(java.lang.String)

It would be great if someone can help me.

Thanks